# How to query location with date range using geoNear command with query in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I used the find is okay：

```
{
    $and:[
        {"online":1},
        {"uptime":{$gte: new Date(2012,8,16,2,51)}}
    ]
}
```

the following command is also okay:

```
{
    geoNear : "Driver", 
    near : [120.105148,30.447977 ],
    num : 100,
    spherical : true,
    maxDistance :500/6378,
    query:{"online":1}
}
```

but I used the geoNear command with Geospatial index, I can't get anythings:

```
{
    geoNear : "Driver", 
    near : [120.105148,30.447977 ],
    num : 100,
    spherical : true,
    maxDistance :500/6378 ,
    query:{
        $and:[
            {"online":1},
            {"uptime":{$gte: new Date(2012,8,16,2,51)}}
        ]
    }
}
```

the requirement is:
I want to get the online clients they update the position in 10 mins, how can do?
I have create the Geospatial index named "pos", inclued the columns:uptime and online

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the $and in the query. If you add two fields, only documents that match both conditions are returned.

Try this:

```
db.runCommand(
    {
        geoNear : "Driver", 
        near : [120.105148,30.447977 ],
        num : 100,
        spherical : true,
        maxDistance :500/6378 ,
        query: { "online": 1,
                 "uptime": {$gte: new Date(2012,8,16,2,51)}

        }
    }
)
```

$and is only required if you want to have two conditions on the same field, or if you want to formulate more complex logical queries involving $and and $or. See the [$and documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/and/#_S_and) for more information.

Comment: thks at first; I must use the $or, and $or is not work;  and now I add a timestap(long ms)to instead of the Date, the command can work.

Answer (score 0):

thks at first;
I used the $or instead of the $and, it also could not work, I need use the $or;
now, I add a Millisecond（long type） column that it convert from the Date column , and I changed the Date column as the following, It worked:

```
{
geoNear : "Driver", 
near : [120.105148,30.447977 ],
num : 100,
spherical : true,
maxDistance :500/6378 ,
query:{
    $or:[
        {"online":2},
        {"online":1,"uptimestap":{$gte: 1348156800000}}
    ]
}
}
```